# Time stamped video to time stamped images

Tags: video, ffmpeg, timestamp, frames

I have a time stamped AVI video file.

I want to create images from the frames of the video but I need them to also have a time associated with them as well.

I can create images from the video through FFmpeg using:

ffmpeg -i video.avi -r 0.1 image_%05.jpeg

However this images do not have a time embedded. Is it possible to also take the time associated with each frame in the video?

My end goal is to sync the time stamp with a GPS track to geotag the images (from the video frames.)

Comment: How is this programming-related?

Answer (score 2):

Stackoverflow is related to programming - this question is more suited to superuser.

To answer you question though, if you are trying to include a timestamp overlay that is present in the original video files, then you can call that stream and maintain the overlay on your output files.

If instead you are trying to generate your own onscreen text relative to the PTS, try:

```
ffmpeg -i video.avi -vf "drawtext=fontfile='c\:\\windows\\fonts\\arialbd.ttf':'%{pts\:hms}':x=0:y=0:fontcolor=white:fontsize=10:box=1:boxcolor=black" /
-f image2 image_%05d.bmp
```

Chang the values at `x=0` and `y=0` to the pixel coordinates where you want the text to being.  Also cahnge the value after `fontsize=` to change the size of the text.

.... sorry for any awkward formating in the ffmpeg command above. I'm still getting used to this myself.

Comment: Nice!  Thanks.  I was wondering how people did that.

How does it look now?  I've added a `\` and separated the rest of the command from the timecode filter.  Should I keep it all in one line, or is it easier to understand the way it is now?